# DbContext code generation stategy fails with Entity framework 5 and VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, dbcontext, entity-framework-5

I have a WPF project in .NET framework 4.5 (VS 2012) and downloaded Entity Framework 5 using NuGet package to the solution.All the documentation regarding Entity Framework 5 says that the Default **Code Generation Strategy** would be **None**(ie DbContext code generation). But in my case, while adding  new ADO.Net Entity Data Model, the **Code Generation Strategy** is **Default**(ie the EF designer generates context class derived from ObjectContext and entity classes derived from EntityObject.).But I want to follow the DbConext code generation mechanism. I'm following Database First approach. Do I miss any settings? or is it that I need to install T4 Template separately?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your project really configured to use .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes. I created the project in VS 2012 with .Net Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have uninstalled VS 2012 RC and installed VS 2012 RTM and now everything works fine.

Comment: I have the same issue. So now I ask: can you upgrade from VS2012-RC to RTM or do u have to uninstall and install the VS2012-RTM via the Microsoft site?! Thanks!

Comment: You can directly install RTM over RC. But only to same edition only(e.g., Professional RC to Professional RTM). For more details check this link : http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility

Answer (score 0):

In Extension Manager -> Download EF 5.x DbContext Generator.
Open Model(edmx) in standart editor, right click on free space and Generate entities using EF 5x DbContext Generator!